# Use SBT To Build Pure Java Project

Tags: java, build, sbt

Historically I have used Ant+Ivy or Maven for building my Java projects.
I'm now looking at non-xml based solutions.

Gradle can compile, jar and publish my project with few issues.

Can I do the same with SBT?
If so, can you provide a simple example of using sbt to build a java only project.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes this is entirely possible. Nothing to setup really, a small build.sbt file should do the trick, something like:

```
organization := "your.group.id"

name := "Your project"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( <any normal jar deps> )
```

And run `sbt package` from the command line.

Comment: I missed the sections in the Getting started guide that mentioned sbt package!      https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Running    https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Java-Sources

Comment: The new location for the second link above is http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Java-Sources

Comment: Running `sbt package` does not seem to be required anymore (unless I'm missing somethig); http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Java-Sources doesn't even mention it.

Comment: Running `sbt package` will generate a jar of your built sources... It is not and never was needed for the setup.

Comment: I like SBT, too, but let's be honest. Will that configuration allow you to publish your project to maven/ivy? Not conveniently, it will append the unnecessary Scala suffix to the package name. Will that configuration allow you to create executable jar-s? No, because `package` does not include dependencies. Will that project be test-able and runnable from within SBT? Yes, that's the only thing that will work out of the box in the described configuration.

Answer (score 33):

For me, it also helped a bit to remove the scala version information from the generated artifact paths, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288859/how-do-you-remove-the-scala-version-postfix-from-artifacts-builtpublished-wi). You'll also want to remove the Scala library as a dependency from any pom or ivy file you publish.

Here's what you'll need:

```
crossPaths := false
autoScalaLibrary := false
```

Comment: `autoScalaLibrary := false` removes the Scala dependency.

Answer (score 13):

Sure, you can. Example configuration:

```
name := "myName"
version := "0.1"
organization := "org.myorganization"

javacOptions in (Compile, compile) ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8", "-g:lines")

crossPaths := false // drop off Scala suffix from artifact names.
autoScalaLibrary := false // exclude scala-library from dependencies
```

**Summing up.** I love SBT, but I felt necessary to write the full build with all the tricky parts of using it for java. Note that this setup might be *better* than a maven one because you'll have nice features such as incremental testing or even incremental runs. Also consider adding `sbt-assembly` plugin if you have dependencies and want to create fat jars (executables).

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice example of build.sbt for pure Java sources at the [Xerial blog](http://xerial.org/blog/2014/03/24/sbt/) including how to publish Maven style artifacts with no Scala version tag.