# Play Framework 2.1.1 not resolving dependencies

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I am trying to run `play dependencies` on my project and it is failing to find my dependencies.  My situation is unique in that I am running on an internal LAN with absolutely no internet access so everything has to be found in either my local repository or the local artifactory.  My Build.scala looks like this:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    "rroc.e.jasfeed" % "ms-common" % "1.2-SNAPSHOT",
    "rroc.e.jasfeed" % "metrics-common" % "1.2-SNAPSHOT"
)

val local = "localhost" at "file:///C:/DevTools/apache-maven-3.0.4/repository/"
val art = "private-repo" at "http://10.10.20.230:8080/artifactory/repo/"

val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.10.1",
    scalaHome := Some(file("C:/DevTools/Scala/scala-2.10.1")),
    autoScalaLibrary := false,
    offline := true,
    ivyLoggingLevel := UpdateLogging.Full,
    resolvers ++= Seq(local,art)
)
```

The first problem I am seeing is that even though I am telling it `offline := true` it continually tries connecting to "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/" which consistently fails because it is not reachable.

Another issue I am seeing is that it is trying to get "rroc/e/jasfeed/ms-common_2.10/1.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml" rather than "rroc/e/jasfeed/ms-common/1.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml."  I thought having `autoScalaLibrary := false` would cause that to stop, but apparently not.

Is there something I am missing/not understanding about how Play/SBT work?  I can't seem to get it to go into true offline mode and I can't seem to make it quit putting the "_2.10" at the end of my dependencies.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem, I'm going to hazard a guess that you still have the Typesafe repository listed in your `plugins.sbt` file.

For your second problem, I think you're after the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288859/how-do-you-remove-the-scala-version-postfix-from-artifacts-builtpublished-wi)

Comment: I checked my `plugins.sbt` file and I had removed the Typesafe repository from there already, but it still insists on trying to look for dependencies there.

I tried adding `crossPaths := false` to my Build.scala, but it is still looking for ms-common_2.10 rather than just ms-common.

Comment: Hmmm ok. Have you tried ``resolvers := Seq(local,art)`` instead? I think this will allow you to overwrite your list of repos, rather than appending to the default list which seems to include Typesafe.